# How to list your application/library/wrapper/script here

Tags: support, faq, libraries, apps, scripts

If you've created an application, script, or library for use on the Stack Exchange network, that's fantastic!

Now **publicize it by creating a question** with the correct tag:

> [app](/questions/tagged/app) https://stackapps.com/questions/ask?tags=app
>
> [library](/questions/tagged/library) https://stackapps.com/questions/ask?tags=library
>
> [script](/questions/tagged/script) https://stackapps.com/questions/ask?tags=script

Generally, you should **only publicize your app if it can actually be used**, but to develop a write-access app, you will need to [set up a placeholder post first.](https://stackapps.com/q/4573/7653)

These questions provide a default template for you to work with. Please follow this rough template; it's presented below for reference.

```
<!-- thumbnail: http://example.com/some-image.png -->
<!-- version: 1.0 -->
<!-- tag: a-tag-on-the-post -->
<!-- excerpt: Up to 200 characters of excerpt -->

### About: (required)

Tell us about your app/library/wrapper/script.  
Why did you create it? Who is it for?   
How does it work? What problem does it solve?

### Screenshot / Code Snippet:  (highly recommended)

Insert a reasonably sized screenshot (or code snippet) of your 
app/wrapper/library/script here, so we can get a quick look at it and 
an idea of how it works and what it might do for us.

### Download / Install: (required)

Provide links for us to obtain your app/library/wrapper/script.  
For websites or service, provide link to the main or home page.  
A user should be able to jump to this section and dive right into your app.

### Platform: (recommended)

What platform or browser is your app/library/wrapper/script for?   
Android? PC? Mac? Apple Newton? Firefox? Opera? Lynx? 

### Contact: (optional)

Who created this app? Who are the key contributors? 
How do we get in touch with them or find them?

### License: (optional)

What license is your app/library/wrapper/script released under, if any? 
Or if it is paid, how much does it cost and how do we buy it?

### Code: (recommended)

What language, frameworks, and tools were used to write this?
Where can we get the code?
How can we contribute to the code?
```

#### Metadata

Thumbnails should be **144 pixels wide, and 119 pixels tall** and a [PNG file](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Network_Graphics) (with extension).  If no thumbnail is provided, one will be generated from the first image in the question if possible; a default will be used if nothing is provided.

The designated tag will be the "+1 tag" that is shown **in addition to** the [app](/questions/tagged/app),[library](/questions/tagged/library), or [script](/questions/tagged/script) tags.  If it is not specified explicitly, the most popular tag on the post will be used instead.  If a tag is explicitly designated, it must exist on the post to take effect.

The version number will **not** be displayed if omitted.

The excerpt **cannot** contain any HTML or markup.  If it is omitted, the first ~200 characters of the About section will be included.  If there is no About section, the first ~200 characters of the post itself will be used.

Comment: This information was really hard to find! Shouldn't it be linked to the front page or FAQ, and if it is and I didn't see it, shouldn't it be emphasized more?

Answer (score 31):

> Remember, **you should only publicize
>   your app if it can actually be used**!

I'm working on an idea for an app.

In true "customer development" fashion, I'd like to publish the idea, with a screenshot of what it will look like, to see what kind of reaction it gets and what features people want it to have. It's not difficult to implement, but I'd rather not rush into it without having some kind of idea whether anyone is interested.

Is it OK to publish without an implementation, to get a sense of what people expect from my app before the first version?

### Answer:

Publish using the (new) [placeholder](/questions/tagged/placeholder) tag.
See "[My app has to be published first? But it's still under development](https://stackapps.com/questions/4573/my-app-has-to-be-published-first-but-its-still-under-development)".

Comment: If its not very complicated to implement, then better just to do it and see what people think. If no-one is interested then you won't have wasted much time anyway.

Comment: Maybe you can just leave the app tag. Then your question doesn't get listed in the app tab, so it's clear that it's not yet a working app.

Comment: this should be posted as a separate question. Anyway, good point for early prototyping. :)

Comment: [I just released my first official Stackapps script](http://stackapps.com/questions/3686/script-to-add-a-related-tags-module-for-search-on-all-stack-exchange-sites), but for before implementing it [I posted the idea on Meta Stack Overflow as a feature request](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/148524/show-related-tags-on-the-search-results-page). So that's one way to go about it.

Comment: _what kind of reaction it gets_ Few people will care about an unimplemented idea. _what features people want it to have_ You need to think about what features you want it to have instead of lazily asking others to do your work. _having some kind of idea whether anyone is interested_ If **you're** not interested, then don't bother. If you **are** interested, then write it.

Answer (score 9):

> ### Historical Note
>
> StackList is no longer available - the features that made it an attractive supplement to listing your app here have found their way into Stack Apps itself.
>
> This answer remains for historical purposes.

Don't forget to also publish your app on <del>stacklist.quickmediasolutions.com</del> <sup>(404 Not Found)</sup>

The site is shaping into a nice user-friendly app-store where anyone can go and have a look at the apps that are available.

As for developers, you get some nice tools for bug tracking, feedback, etc.

**Please pay StackList a visit today!**

Comment: I hate that the site forces people to sign in with just an OpenID. Then, the link that it gives you to get an OpenID, if you don't have one, doesn't work. I just signed up and have no idea where to find my OpenID. VERY ANNOYING!!!!

Comment: After signing up for an account on Launchpad, you can login by entering `https://launchpad.net/~your-nickname` where `your_nickname` is your username on the site.

Comment: ATM, the site is retuning a `Internal Server Error` response.

Answer (score 4):

#### I have written a chat bot. Do I need to announce its existence on Stack Apps?

No, it is not mandatory to announce your chat bot with a post on Stack Apps.

It is appreciated if you do, specially if your bot is present in public chat rooms and users stumble upon it. See your post as a service to (potential) users in case of questions / issues / bugs or complaints about your bot.

You can choose to either post under your own account or that of your bot account. In either case make clear you are the owner and therefore responsible for its (re)actions.

Use the [app](/questions/tagged/app) tag if your chatbot operates headless, on a server. Use the [script](/questions/tagged/script) tag if your bot is a userscript that relies on a browser and a script manager. Add the [chat](/questions/tagged/chat) tag as well.

From [Etiquette of Screen-scraping Stack Overflow?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/446)

> **Identify yourself**. Add something useful to the user-agent (ideally, a link to an URL, or something informational) so we can see your bot as something other than "generic unknown anonymous scraper."

Proper User-Agents are for example:

- [`SmokeDetector/git (+https://github.com/Charcoal-SE/SmokeDetector)`](https://github.com/Charcoal-SE/SmokeDetector/blob/d1828a766a508d8c3e9d8086fb17d7996cbab00c/helpers.py#L234)
- [`KennyBot/0.1 (+https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/269324/kennybot)`](https://glitch.com/edit/#!/mse-so-se-chatbot?path=server%2Fsimplebrowser.js%3A110%3A38)
- [`HotQuestionScraper/1.0 https://lackadaisical-appeal.glitch.me/ https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/158100/rene`](https://glitch.com/edit/#!/lackadaisical-appeal?path=hotness.js%3A19%3A25)

Comment: For example, can I add my other profile's (which is not a bot) link also in user agent like you've added yours?

Comment: @Rosie yes, you can