# Rep Change Notifier for Android

Tags: app, notifier, android

### About

Just a simple Python script I threw together to notify me through my Android phone if my reputation is changed. I created it for my own personal use but figured I might as well throw it out into the community.

#### License

[MIT License](http://www.opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.php)

#### Download

The Python script and basic instructions on how to use it are located on [Google Code](http://code.google.com/p/stack-droid-notifier/). In order to use the script edit this portion:

```
#Personalization Items
site = 'stackoverflow'
usrid = '68172'
timeframe = (60*60)
#End Personalization Items
```

#### Platform

[Android-Scripting-Environment](http://code.google.com/p/android-scripting/) on Android powered phones

### Contact

[StackOverflow CV](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/peck)
[Google Profile](http://www.google.com/profiles/soldier.moth)

### Code

Written in Python on my Motorola Droid using the [Android-Scripting-Environment](http://code.google.com/p/android-scripting/). Source code hosted at [Google Code](http://code.google.com/p/stack-droid-notifier/source/browse/stack-droid-notifier/stack-droid-notifier.py).

Comment: Wow - I didn't know about android-scripting-environment! Good job. I'll try and give it a go when I get a chance.

Comment: please format your app using the [faq] template (  http://stackapps.com/questions/7/how-to-list-your-application-library-wrapper-here ) for consistency with other [app]s.

Comment: @Kevin - thanks for that link, I've edited the post and will try to put up a screenshot as soon as possible.

Answer (score 4):

[Droidstack](https://stackapps.com/questions/585/droidstack-for-android-1-0-4b-now-with-notifications) now provides this functionality :)

Answer (score 1):

There is already an Android widget called [SOFlair](http://www.androlib.com/android.application.org-ocactus-soflair-zEz.aspx) that does a similar job. I think it doesn't use the API and possibly just screen-scrapes.

I installed it a few months ago, although it wasn't great as it has very little configuration and its update interval was too low.

Comment: I actually have that installed as well, but it doesn't notify of rep changes. I created this script to provide a temporary solution until I create a better dedicated android app.