# Make site icons have transparent backgrounds

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, icons

This is a request to make the site's icons have transparent backgrounds. They are already PNGs, so they support that. This would make applications such as [Droidstack](https://stackapps.com/questions/585/droidstack-for-android) look much better.

---

Although stackapps is the only one that has a non-white background, all the others have solid white backgrounds. Although this is not immediately annoying, it suddenly becomes so when putting a different background on an icon (for example when clicking on an item in Droidstack, the background turns orange but there's a nasty white square around the icon.. I'll try to upload a new video of it soon).

Comment: + while i am sure that the image in toto is a branding issue, isolated images would be nice.

Comment: @code poet: I'm not sure what you're talking about, I was referring to the `icon_url` images as returned by some API calls.

Comment: Felix, have you checked out this http://stackapps.com/questions/347/svg-versions-of-the-logos? I've used that useful package for my app and yes, they have trasparent backgrounds.

Comment: This is [status-planned].  As the quickest path to ground, the API is serving up resources we already had laying around.  Eventually they'll be cleaned up explicitly for API purposes.

Comment: @sys Yes, but being able to fetch the icons from the API itself is much more versatile. @Kevin, thanks

Comment: Yes, transparent pngs looks better.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `icon_url` images returned by StackAuth (and `/stats`) should all now have transparent backgrounds.

Comment: I know I can figure this out for myself, but, have the URLs changed, or are they the same? (just need to know if I should re-cache my images)

Comment: @Farseeker - the same.

Comment: @Kevin: Does this include the logos for the beta sites?

Comment: Cool banana, thanks. @George, looks like the beta sites are still solid

Comment: @George - the beta site logos are squares... so there is no difference between a solid background and a transparent one.

Answer (score 1):

I hope this request will be onored as soon as possible, please.
Sites number to support is growing fast and this flaw does not allow us to use StackAuth sites method without breaking our layout.