# Problems with the Site Icons

Tags: bug, status-completed, icons

I'm having trouble with the WebApps icon being returned from the `/sites` method.

Namely, the image is composed of a larg white rectangle with a very small guy in the middle.

- Why can't the guy take up the whole image?
- Why is the background not transparent?

These issues lead to the following problem on my mobile site: *(look in the upper right corner)*

http://stackmobile.com/site.php?site=webapps.stackexchange

http://files.quickmediasolutions.com/icon_trouble.png

Compare that with one of the other sites:
http://stackmobile.com/site.php?site=stackoverflow

Is there nothing that can be done about this?

Comment: See my question here: http://stackapps.com/questions/793/make-site-icons-have-transparent-backgrounds they'll all be transparent by 1.0 (or else!)

Answer (score 2):

You're not using the icons provided by stackauth on non-WebApps pages, thus the break.

Also, the icon provided by WebApps is temporary as is... well, nearly everything else about it.  Don't expect the little construction man to stay forever.

---

Icons served now have transparent backgrounds.  Beta site icons are less... beta-y, but still beta-enough.

Comment: Will the backgrounds be transparent when the real logo gets released? And yes, I know the other icons are not from StackAuth - for obvious reasons.

Comment: Should we even be supporting WebApps when it's in the beta phase?

Comment: @Matt - you can read data out just fine, so if that's all your [app] does why not?  If, however, your [app] extends a site (like, a chrome extension for instance) or redirects back to the site (in a way that makes it difficult to conditionally disable such functionality) probably not.  So, it depends really.

Comment: Back to the question, though... will the background be made transparent? That would be awesome because otherwise, we're forced to have an image with a white background on a page that... doesn't have a white background.