# StackWidget for Android

Tags: app, widget, android

## StackWidget 1.1

---

[image]

### Screenshots

[image][image]

### About

StackOverflow home screen widget.
Displays hottest question - click widget to see top 10 hottest.

New in 1.1:
- Change question category (newest, by tag)
- Switch to other StackExchange sites
- Change update frequency

Coming soon:
- Save questions and get notified when they get answers

This is only my second Android app and my first widget. Really just doing this to learn, but if people want to use it, here you go! It's on the market and also on Google Code.

**New version adds some extra settings (adds support for specifying tags, changing the StackExchange site, setting update interval), changes styles.**

#### License

New BSD License

#### Download

http://code.google.com/p/sowidget/

[image]

#### Platform

Android 1.6+

### Contact

Made by me in my spare time over a couple of days. Leave your feedback here or on the Android Market.

### Code

Source code on Google Code (click the ling up there, I can only post 1 link) I warn you, it isn't the prettiest. Not well documented ATM but as I add features I'll comment it up.

Comment: Did you use an API wrapper provided by this site?

Comment: I think you have enough rep now...

Comment: Woop, pretty pictures. jjnguy - no, I didn't, since all I'm doing right now is some pretty lightweight JSON parsing. When/if I develop it I'll look into them - this was just a see-if-I-can-do-it deal. There's another app on here, Droidstack - looks pretty good, I might see if the owner is up for a merge or something.

Comment: @blork, if you decide to use a wrapper, let Bill and/or me know what you think of stackwrap4j if you look at it.

Comment: The logo is awesome. I'll see if I can try this out later.

Comment: **Hey!** I just had the greatest idea - when a user clicks on a question in the widget, why not redirect them to the appropriate page on http://StackMobile.com ?

Comment: @George Edison That's a great idea! I didn't even realize someone had made a mobile version, much nicer than loading up the full size sites. I'll make a quick change and upload 1.11. And thanks!

Also, I've had one review on the market saying the app didn't appear in their widget list. Anyone else had this problem? I'm testing on 1.6 in the emulator and 2.1 on my device, and I've no problems. Could someone with Sense let me know?

Comment: @blork: **Awesome!** is all I can say. I fired up my Android Emulator (I don't actually have an Android phone) and it looks great! Thanks for integrating with my site - these two apps together make for the best Android experience possible.

Comment: Just updated to 1.12. Fixed a few bugs, added sorting options, better update scheduling.

Comment: That's an awesome icon!

Comment: @blork You *can* [integrate with Droidstack](http://code.google.com/p/droidstack/wiki/Intents) :) (not trying to steal George's thunder)

Comment: @blork I added StackWidget to my [IntegratingApps](http://code.google.com/p/droidstack/wiki/IntegratingApps) wiki page :)

Answer (score 5):

## Version 1.3 (new features!)

Posting update here so it's more visible.

- A lot more user control - number of questions, sorting, tags.
- Long press on questions to save them to favourites.
- By default you will receive notifications when favourites get new answers.
- Pressing question will take to you StackMobile version of site for improved mobile browsing.
- Performance increase (list rendering should be improved).

### Coming in 1.4:

- Automatically favouriting questions by a user so you can get notifications when your own questions are answered.

Questions, comments, suggestions?

### Screenshots:

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: 1.31 with manual refresh option just uploaded to market

Comment: Updated to use API version 1.0

Comment: Updated to add support for all current and future StackExchange sites

Comment: Added Droidstack integration (http://stackapps.com/questions/585/droidstack-for-android-1-0-3b)

Comment: Is this still being updated? The market claims that the current version is 1.5 ...

Comment: I haven't updated this post for a while, but 1.5 was mainly to fix a bug anyway. I might still add to the app in future but it isn't a priority for me right now.