# Drafting users for testing in Alpha/Beta stage?

Tags: discussion, apps, release

I finally stopped stagnating long enough to start working on an application for Stack Apps using the API. Development is going well and within the next 6 to 8 weeks there will be enough functionality for the application to be usable.

I am hoping to be able release the application using a release early/release often methodology, however after a quick chat with Rebecca and reading [How to list your app](https://stackapps.com/questions/7/how-to-list-your-application-library-wrapper-here) I need  some clarification on Jeff's comment:

> Remember, you should only **publicize your app if it can actually be used!**

Effectively I would like to add my application to Stack Apps, and for the initial Alpha/Beta release have users email me requesting access to the application, allowing for a controlled environment of testing before throwing the application out to the world.

Would this be acceptable within the Stack Apps listing, or should I only list the application here once it is available for download by everyone? Alternatively, what would be the best way to get users testing a new Stack Apps application?

Comment: It's pretty much fine to list it now. I've had mine listed for ages and its not released. Stack apps isn't a active site concerning new "questions" so it's not like it would "get in the way". Just tag the question as "apps" not as "app" (until it is released, then you remove the s)

Comment: I don't read Jeff's comment as "bug-free" or "feature-complete" just "(unqualified) usable".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is acceptable, so long as it is *usable in some form*.

What we object to is people listing an [app](/questions/tagged/app) that exists only in their imagination and not reality. That's not helping people looking for, y'know, actual apps that run on our API...