# Why aren't my application icons being used in the "Top Apps" list?

Tags: support

I've got application icons listed for each of my apps, but the "Top Apps" list shows the default "pages with gears" icon instead.

Each time I've registered the application before posting a question on StackApps, and then updated the application's registration when I'd created the relevant post.

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1):

When you post the app use the predefined format. At the top there are parameters you can set including the icon that is displayed.

You get to the formats by asking a question with the tag already specified:

https://stackapps.com/questions/ask?tags=*app*

For scripts/libraries, substitute *app* with *script* and *library*

Comment: So... what's the point of entering the data on the "register application" page?  Is that used elsewhere?

Comment: The register application page gets you your API key which allows your app to make many more requests to the API, it also allows you to use API methods that require authentification and the description/app-title/app-icon you enter there is used for the window that users see when they permit your app to access their data. If you make a script which doesn't use te API then you don't need to Fill out the "register application" page. If your app doesn't use the API then usually stack apps is not the place to list it

Answer (score 0):

For app listings, we're currently still using the `<!-- thumbnail: blah -->` syntax [from this post](https://stackapps.com/questions/7/how-to-list-your-application-library-wrapper-script-here).  This may change eventually, but it's not a really high priority.

We're showing the provided image to users when they authenticate or manage their apps.

Example:

[image]

There is a propagation delay after changing an icon, as we're syncing them to our CDN.