# OBSOLETE - Stack Apps Listing Wizard - Making it easier to list your application right here on Stack Apps

Tags: script, obsolete, stackapps

### Screenshot

[image]

### About

Listing an application here on Stack Apps can be a lot of work. First you have to visit [this question](https://stackapps.com/q/7) and copy the markdown. Some of those fields don't apply to UserScripts and some don't apply for commercial applications - those need to be removed. And then there is the thumbnail - you need to open a separate tab to upload an image and then copy-and-paste the URL. Then if you want to link to a certain license, you need to dig that up...

All in all, this can be a very time consuming process - especially if all you want to do is list a tiny UserScript. Therefore I have written a UserScript that (after you click on the toolbar button) asks the user a series of questions and then generates the page title, body (including markdown), and tags. There is even a convenient button to upload the thumbnail image :)

For the curious - this very listing was generated using the script.

#### License

Stack Apps Listing Wizard is released under the [MIT License](http://www.opensource.org/licenses/MIT)

#### Download

You can download Stack Apps Listing Wizard here:
http://files.quickmediasolutions.com/userscripts/stackapps_listing.user.js

### Contact

I can be reached at `admin@quickmediasolutions.com`.

### Code

Stack Apps Listing Wizard is written in JavaScript.

Comment: This should be intergrated with StackApps by default.

Comment: If possible the 'tags' should auto-complete like the main page does.. I find the only thing I ***need*** to review is the tags. otherwise perfect! :P

Comment: @rlemon: Thank you - I can easily make the tags auto-complete just like the actual tag entry box.

Comment: That would turn this script from uber to epic!