# Are "api-key" and "app-key" the same thing?

Tags: support, meta, api-key, terminology

When tagging my last couple of questions about registering for a key, I noticed there are two similar-looking tags:

> - [api-key](/questions/tagged/api-key) - 35 uses and a tag wiki
> - [app-key](/questions/tagged/app-key) - <s>10 uses</s> (Update: retagged), no tag wiki

- Do they both refer to the same thing?
- Is "api key" the correct term we should all be using?
- Should "app key" be made a tag synonym of "api key"? Should we just retag all the latter?
- Or are there really two different concepts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answer:  Yes they are the same.
Officially now, since [`app-key` was made a synonym of](https://stackapps.com/questions/7348/moderation-request-please-make-app-key-a-synonym-of-api-key) [api-key](/questions/tagged/api-key).