# Moderation request: Please make `app-key` a synonym of `api-key`

Tags: support, status-completed, meta

Refer to [Are "api-key" and "app-key" the same thing?](https://stackapps.com/questions/3740/are-api-key-and-app-key-the-same-thing).

Although I've now retagged the questions that used [app-key](/questions/tagged/app-key), there are [still plenty of places](https://stackapps.com/search?tab=newest&q=%22app%20key%22) where the [redundant term is used](https://stackapps.com/search?q=%22app%20keys%22).
The terms are interchangeable here, but we only need one tag, so please make [app-key](/questions/tagged/app-key) a synonym of [api-key](/questions/tagged/api-key).