# How can I introduce my Stack Overflow app to other users?

Tags: support, questions, stackoverflow

Recently, I created [a project](https://github.com/Bluebird7/poptop) to manage and extract questions from Stack Overflow and convert those to PDF docs. I put it on GitHub.

I think this project could be improved and could be very helpful to other Stack Overflow users. How do I want share this project with other users?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's no one way. Here's a recipe you can use:

1. Make a proper app post here on StackApps.
   See **[How to list your application/library/wrapper/script here](https://stackapps.com/questions/7/how-to-list-your-application-library-wrapper-script-here)**.
2. Look for posts on [Meta Stack Overflow (MSO)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/) and/or on [Meta Stack Exchange (MSE)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/) where your app might make part of a ***good*** answer.
   If you find such posts, make *proper* answer(s) to them -- linking both to the app post you made in step 1 and directly to where they can install the app.
   Be sure your answers meet all the regular criteria of a proper answer and avoid "spammy" behavior.
3. If you can't find such posts, you can create [a self-answered question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) on MSO and/or MSE -- **provided that such question and answer are appropriate to the site**.
4. If you have a blog, Facebook, Twitter etc. You can promote your app there, too.

---

<sub>PS: You can always pay me large sums of cash for advertising purposes. Results are not guaranteed. YMMV. (^_^)</sub>

Comment: Thanks for complete answer! ;)  self-answered question was a good idea! ;)

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/287181/is-there-any-app-that-could-extract-and-manage-questions-from-stackoverflow

Comment: Oh dear, that's not what I meant.  Your post *here* should be per [this](http://stackapps.com/questions/7/how-to-list-your-application-library-wrapper-script-here).  Your posts on other sites must address a need, that other people have, that is fully within the purview of that other site.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that you have coded all the bits that you can do first. This ensures that any request for help is genuine. If the project idea is any good, you should find that, although you can't get what you want, you can get what you need.

Have you tried [Microsoft's CodePlex](https://www.codeplex.com/). From here you can create a 'publishable', and also advertise (for free) job requirements. Github is good for development, CodePlex is better at promoting projects.