# Stackopedia - all the answers to the questions you never asked

Tags: app, questions, android

### Screenshots

#### Splashscreen

[image: SplashScreen]

#### Random Questions

[image: Random Question#1]
[image: Random Question#2]
[image: Random Question#3]
[image: Random Question#4]

#### Settings

[image: Settings#1]
[image: Settings#2]
[image: Settings#3]

### About

An Android app that shows a random high voted question and its best answer each time you launch it. A really different way to learn new things, an interesting (and often funny) way to spend some time.

### Version 1.5

Add support for SE beta sites
Add support for customization of search parameters

### Version 1.2

Add bookmarks feature

#### License

Totally free, ads-powered.

#### Download

Available right now, just a click away from you on the [Google Play Store](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=it.mbz.apps.stackopedia).

#### Platform

Only Android, sorry, and at least Jelly Bean.

### Contact

Feedback highly appreciated: just drop me a note here, or mail me; address can be found on the store page.

### Code

Written in Java, HTML and Javascript.

### Credits

The users of [SE English Language & Usage](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/225257/use-and-meaning-of-o-between-words-in-blends) for (unknowingly) helping me choose a name.

Comment: Lol. It refuse to show the thumbnail...can someone solve it, please? :D

Comment: Read [the FAQ post](http://stackapps.com/q/7/7653) again.  **The thumbnail must be 144 x 119 pixels and PNG format.**  I replaced your image with one of mine and it works just fine [where it's supposed to](http://stackapps.com/questions/tagged/app?sort=newest&pageSize=50).  Reformat your thumb and edit it in.

Comment: "Thumbnails should be" in the FAQ pointed me in the wrong direction, now it shows. Thanks.

Comment: Looks good. Are you planning one for iOS?

Comment: @Greenonline: first, thanks for the edits; not using it often, my English is worsening year by year. About iOS version: I'm not an iOS programmer, so I have no plans for it. Even if I'd like such a port, so if someone volunteer for that I'd gladly share my code with him. In the end most of the code is reusable, porting should be easy. That said, unless Google Developer Console has problems this app has not yet a single download from outside those few friends of mine; not that I was expecting zillions of users, but at least a few from the SE network. Dunno if an iOS version is a waste of time.

Comment: Your English is good, don't worry. "Dunno if an iOS version is a waste of time." - If an iOS version never gets written then you will never know... :-) BTW, the thumbnail still appears to not be working.