# Why does dropdown comes in "Rev" when we edit published app?

Tags: support, meta, editing

I have published an app and editing it. One new "Rev" tab is created and it is giving me a dropdown as shown  here[image]. Why it is being created here? It is not created in any other Stack Exchange websites when we edit question. Is it related to

```
<!-- version: 0.0 -->
```

as explained here: [How to list your application/library/wrapper/script here](https://stackapps.com/q/7)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is either a bug or an incomplete feature.  See:

- [**What is the 'rev' dropdown supposed to do?**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/243787/what-is-the-rev-dropdown-supposed-to-do)
- [Stack Exchange Revisions Dropdown Does Nothing?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/258689/stack-exchange-revisions-dropdown-does-nothing)

This extra dropdown *seems* to require:

1. That the post have had previous edits.
2. That the ***page mode*** editor is invoked.

   1. This editor is the default for low-rep users under at least some conditions.  (low rep still being less than 2000, best I can tell).
   2. High-rep users can invoke this editor by control-clicking on the *edit* link.
3. The presence of the `<!-- version: 0.0 -->` comment makes no difference.
4. <sub>Replicating this is a little flaky for me. There *might* be another factor involved.</sub>