# Where is "Stack Exchange API Documentation" listed?

Tags: support

I have followed [How to list your application/library/wrapper/script here](https://stackapps.com/q/7) to list my application. In https://stackapps.com/users/apps/{my-user-id} [image], I find that I have given it access to "Stack Exchange API Documentation". I can't find it listed on the Stack Apps website. Where it is?

Also, if the app had `private_info` access then, it would be good. Now, we have to filter out properties like `comment.upvoted`, `answer.upvoted`, `answer.downvoted`, `answer.accepted`, `question.upvoted`, `question.downvoted`, `question.favorited` and like that many.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're trying some features right in the docs and this features require access token, it's requesting access to your token; if you approve, it appears as application.

E.g., if you click "Get Token" button on the https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/notifications, you'll get:

> [image]

As for being listed it on Stack Apps: it isn't,  as it's an app from SE.

Comment: This does not answer my question.

Comment: @amitjha How doesn't it? If your main question is where is it on the Stack Apps website, then I have to tell you nowhere. This is an official app and it isn't listed on this site nor as do official Android and iOS apps, winter bash,  etc.