# Is my script's API usage okay?

Tags: support, api-v2.2, python, meta

I've written a [short Python script](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/124479/from-q-to-compiler-in-less-than-30-seconds) to help people review C and C++ questions on Code Review.  It uses the API version 2.2.

I've already asked there for a review of that Python code, but I would like to also ask here if I'm using the API correctly and that neither I nor the code is doing anything that causes harm.
If there's a better way to ask this question, or there's documentation I should read, please let me know that, too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't really a place to code-review your script, even if it uses the API.
Here is were you would [**publish** your script](https://stackapps.com/questions/7/how-to-list-your-application-library-wrapper-script-here)<sup>1</sup>.

However, after a *quick* glance at the code, I don't see any glaring problems.
But, if you start making lots, or rapid, calls you will need to check and respect [the `backoff` value](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/wrapper) and [the `quota_remaining` value](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/wrapper).

The **API documentation is at [api.stackexchange.com/docs](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs).**

---

<sup>1 You could also ask about specific problems with the API, or you could beg the community to write a Stack Exchange tool for you ([script-request](/questions/tagged/script-request)).</sup>