# Get our Stack Exchange inbox as native notification on Chrome

Tags: app, inbox, notifications

#### About

I'm new to the Stack Exchange sites. So I was looking for Chrome Extensions get make my experience better. I searched for a **simple and good looking** Notification app. I found nothing so I make mine.

#### Screenshot

[image]
[image]

#### Download

- Here you can download it from the [Chrome Webstore](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/cgamemjjkiapnidkadephhkneocmcino/)
- To report a bug / suggest a feature... [here](https://github.com/fralec/Stack-notifications/issues/new)

#### Platform

Only avalaible on the Chrome Webstore, maybe later on other platforms.

#### Contact

[To stay in touch](https://fralec.com)

#### License

So the extension is naturally completely free. It's under GPL v3.0 license.

#### Code

Full JS, see it [here](https://github.com/fralec/Stack-notifications)

Comment: See http://stackapps.com/questions/7/how-to-list-your-application-library-wrapper-script-here for how to better list your app.