# Stack Flower: a simple Android app for searching Stack Overflow

Tags: app, android

[Stack Flower](http://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.driodan.stackflower&hl=en) is a simple Android app for browsing Stack Overflow, with some useful search customization options. You can easily make queries like

- Posts from this week tagged "android", ranked by number of upvotes.
- Most recent posts tagged "python" with "tensorflow" in the title.
- Most popular posts of all time with specific tags and title text.

If you click on an interesting post in the list of responses, it will open the original Stack Overflow link in your web browser.

I originally wrote this as a simple tool for my own use, so that I could view recent "android" posts ordered by upvotes. Possibly there were other tools that could do this for me, but most seemed to offer sorting by date, or by upvotes, but not both at the same time.

After I'd written the first version for myself, I thought that other programmers with other interests might find it useful with some slight generalization. Thus I replaced the hard-coded queries I'd originally written for my own use with the more general interface that you see here. <sub>(Click for larger view)</sub>

[image: Simple search interface]
[image: Sample search results]

If you're interested in trying [Stack Flower](http://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.driodan.stackflower&hl=en), you can download it for free from the Google Play Store. It should work on any Android device running API 15+ (ie, Ice Cream Sandwich 4.0.4 or higher).

Constructive suggestions for improvement are welcome.

Comment: Might add some screenshots and [other info](https://stackapps.com/questions/7/how-to-list-your-application-library-wrapper-script-here)...

Comment: Better now? Any other suggestions?

Comment: Better.  Re: `"Any other suggestions?"`... Yes, don't chew up so much scenery! ;) And Crop the photos tighter (right now, over 25% of each image is wasted on border and device frame). Also, consider the format previously linked.

Comment: Heh. Thanks for the editing help. I actually wanted the images side-by-side, but didn't know I could do it so easily here.