# PLACEHOLDER - register my app, nothing special

Tags: app, placeholder

Just a post to register my app, nothing special

Comment: Any ideas or goal to share yet ?

Comment: please see https://stackapps.com/questions/7/how-to-list-your-application-library-wrapper-script-here?noredirect=1&lq=1