# What happens if an app becomes super popular?

Tags: discussion, limits

Will there be provisions for apps to become "sponsored" by SO wherein the limits are removed? Say somebody writes the de-facto iPhone app and it gets 500,000 users, the 10K cap will be hit pretty quickly.

Answer (score 10):

According to [Getting Started with the API](https://stackapps.com/questions/2/getting-started-with-the-api), the 10K cap is per-IP address. Thus, the API limit for an iPhone app would be per user, not for the whole app.

Comment: This is correct.

Comment: This does not, however, work for a website, which may have only two or three IPs from which to make requests.

Comment: Yeah a service based app is a no go. :(

Comment: I opened a feature request for adding support for people to request per-key limit increase - http://stackapps.com/questions/61/api-key-limit-increase-support