# API key limit increase support

Tags: feature-request, api-key

One of the things that came up in the discussion on [this question](https://stackapps.com/questions/56/what-happens-if-an-app-becomes-super-popular) was the fact that the 10K limits might not be enough for websites that want to use the SE API.

It might be a good idea to add a `Request key limit increase` link on the app page or at least a note explaining what is the official way of making such requests.

**Update:** [How API keys work](https://stackapps.com/questions/67/how-api-keys-work) just got updated with some info that touches this topic.

I still think it would be a terrific idea if the app management page actually showed some rough stats on how close to hitting the key limit it's coming to and had a link to that particular question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [this post](https://stackapps.com/questions/67/how-api-keys-work) for our policies related to API Keys and quotas.

Answer (score 0):

This is a great idea. My [mobile site](http://m.stackoverflow.quickmediasolutions.com) will definitely need a higher limit as more and more people begin to use it.

Maybe there should be some kind of form we can fill in explaining why we need more, etc. Then it can be granted on a case by case basis.

Comment: I suppose you could always make your site utilise AJAJ so that, if the user has it on their phone, the requests will come from their IP, thus removing the quota problem.

Comment: Of course, if the user doesn't have JS, then it's going to be a bit hard.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is when this happens, you'll be able to make some sort of deal with the dev team by emailing team@stackoverflow.com

Comment: Sure. Still, it'd be nice to have that option explicitly listed on the App management page. In fact, it'd be nice if the API server watches apps that hit the limit for certain period of time and sets a flag for the link to be highlighted on the App management page.

Answer (score -2):

It strikes me this might be a possible revenue stream for the team.

(Don't everyone downvote at once.)

Comment: Okay, we'll space out the downvotes.

Comment: I can only hope the team gives me some upvote love. ;-)

Comment: I held back on my down vote for 4 minutes.

Comment: Actually, @Joel does have a point. After all, SE is a for-profit org and the team needs to find a way to monetize their efforts. That point did cross my mind as I was writing my question, I just didn't want to be the first one to put it in writing. :-)

Comment: Don't worry @Franci. I'll take this hit for you, but I expect you to take the next one. :-P