# What is the syntax for specifying parameters?

Tags: support, url-syntax

How do I specify a parameter in the URL?

http://api.stackoverflow.com/0.8/questions works as expected.

Then I would like to pass parameter *body* with a value of *true* (that is available according to the [documentation for /questions](http://api.stackoverflow.com/0.8/help/method?method=questions)).

I have tried:

```
http://api.stackoverflow.com/0.8/questions/body{true}
```

and

```
http://api.stackoverflow.com/0.8/questions/body(true)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Like so, in the query section of the URL:

```
http://api.stackoverflow.com/0.8/questions/?body=true&field=value&field1=value1
```

See [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string).

Comment: I think this information should be in http://stackapps.com/questions/2/getting-started-with-the-api. That is where I looked first.

Comment: @Peter. Example added.