# Request with Invalid key still return the content and rate limit stepped down into No Key Limit

Tags: bug, status-completed

For example

> http://api.stackoverflow.com/0.8/stats?key=TEST1234&type=jsontext

Request with Invalid key still return the content and rate limit stepped down into No Key Limit

```
X-Ratelimit-Current 290
X-Ratelimit-Max 300
```

Even If I change key to another invalid key, its still continue to decrement `X-Ratelimit-Current`

But this [getting started page](https://stackapps.com/questions/2/getting-started-with-the-api) says

> Requests with invalid or revoked keys
>   are not completed, they are **not**
>   stepped down to the No Key limit.

**Edit**: Fixed!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now, requesting with invalid API key returns following

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 4000,
    "message": "The 'key' query parameter containing your application's public key is missing or invalid."
  }
}
```

So, it has been fixed now!

Answer (score 0):

I can confirm that this indeed works even with the wrong key.

And furthermore, it seems that **any** request with an invalid ID is being completed.

- http://api.stackoverflow.com/0.8/users?key=test1234&type=jsontext
- http://api.stackoverflow.com/0.8/questions?key=test1234&type=jsontext

Definitely a bug. For sure.