# API Key limit 10k is Per IP Address or Globally?

Tags: bug, support, status-norepro, rate-limit, api-key

[Getting started FAQ](https://stackapps.com/questions/2/getting-started-with-the-api) says No Key limit is IP Address based, but it does not say for with API Key.

When I test my API Key from different IP Addresses, I noticed that 10k limit is globally, limit is getting decreased, across different IP Address.

Can I assume that is the correct way? or bug?

**Edit**: Fixed!

Comment: That would have to be a bug if true. It wouldn't make any sense to limit all users of an application from a single pool of calls.

Comment: @Colin: That is the way it is being handled right now.

Comment: It would only take 34 users to be better off not using a key. o_O

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Now, I can confirm that changing my IP Address reset rate-limit to 10000 back.

So, 10k limit is per IP Address, not globally.