# What's the best way to mashup a social network with StackOverflow?

Tags: support, api, users

I’m experimenting with an integration project where I mashup a user’s LinkedIn connections and StackOverflow activity. Are there any relevant APIs on StackOverflow that could be used to integrate StackOverflow data with a user's network?

Comment: I don't really care as long as it supports OpenID as a login method :)

Answer (score 1):

https://stackapps.com/faq

[API "Hello World" code](https://stackapps.com/questions/2/getting-started-with-the-api)

http://api.stackoverflow.com/0.8/help

Comment: + for stating the obvious. I forget, is there a 'first time here? read the FAQ' banner here that introduces the API?

Comment: @code: Just log out and you'll find out.

Comment: Thanks! Those api docs help quite a bit.  One thing I couldn't find was how I might connect users on one site (with email addresses and names) with the equivalent user on StackOverflow.  Is there a quick way to search for users by email on the APIs?

Comment: @geo - again, +1 for stating the obvious.

Comment: @puffer - you are going to have to somehow get the user_id of at least one of the user's stack exchange accounts, pull that user and get the associated_id and then hit the stackauth users/{id}/associated path. *if* you had a complete list of users you could search for the email hash. I say *if* because keeping a complete current list is something you want to be careful with so that you don't piss off the api abuse gods. I am putting the final touches on a cacheing strategy that makes keeping an updated list tolerable. Watch for the post.

Comment: @code - yes, the ability to look up a user's ID from a list of cached email hashes would be perfect.  Thanks for the tip, and I look forward to your upcoming post.

Comment: @code what's the stackauth path if my associated_id is 1234-5678?

http://api.stackoverflow.com/0.8/users/1234-5678/associated doesn't seem to be working.

      error: {
          code: 404
          message: "The server has not found anything matching the Request-URI."
      }

Comment: @porkeypop the path should look like this example: http://stackauth.com/0.8/users/6c21dcdc-0b55-440f-a378-9871074a5350/associated?type=json

I added the type=json to make it return pretty-print instead of standard json.