# How to use the Stack Exchange API in PhoneGap?

Tags: support, api, jsonp

I want to write a program using [PhoneGap](http://phonegap.com/). How can I use [the Stack Exchange API](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs) in PhoneGap?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't used PhoneGap yet, but they claim that you develop apps with plain old JS, CSS, and HTML.

If that's true, then use the API just like you would from a web page -- with simple AJAX calls.

Here's a working example (using jQuery):

```js
var userID      = 1416412;
var pageNum     = 1;
var pageSize    = 100;
var siteParam   = 'stackoverflow';
var appKey      = 'Get your own key!';

$.ajax ( {
    type:       'GET',
    url:        'https://api.stackexchange.com/2.1/users/' + userID
                + '/answers?page=' + pageNum
                + '&pagesize=' + pageSize + '&order=desc&sort=votes'
                + '&site=' + siteParam
                + '&filter=!3u0zcO(lpHVEGuskA&key=' + appKey,
    dataType:   'JSON',
    cache:      true,
    success:    function (apiJson) {
                    //-- Provide a closure.
                    console.log (apiJson);
                }
} );
```

[Get a key](https://stackapps.com/apps/oauth/register), it greatly increases your quota and is needed if you want one of the methods that needs authentication.

Reference [**the API docs**](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs) and the [**API “Hello World” code**](https://stackapps.com/questions/2/api-hello-world-code).

Comment: I dont think "cache: true" is appropriate because its very much possible that the answer might have been edited.

Comment: @BhavikShah, this cache has nothing to do with that and will not miss updates.  It's just about not refetching the *exact same* data unnecessarily.