# How can I extract user information on Stack Overflow using Python and the Stack Overflow API?

Tags: support, api, python

I am new to Python. I want to extract a user bio, answers, questions they made in Stack Overflow.
Can I do that using the API? For example, can I extract the user: name bio and number of questions answered, using the API, from this URL: https://stackoverflow.com/users/4189194/krishna?tab=profile?

Answer (score 4):

The API presents individual features behind individual URLs. The information on the profile page is combined from several sources; to get the details you requested, you will have to submit multiple requests. Probably start at [the API "Hello World" Python example](https://stackapps.com/a/7169/17434) and consult [the official documentation](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs) for the precise API endpoints; for example, https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/users/874188?site=stackoverflow.com gets me

```json
{"items":[{"badge_counts":{"bronze":263,"silver":203,"gold":24},"account_id":468289,"is_employee":false,"last_modified_date":1617888900,"last_access_date":1617901099,"reputation_change_year":4789,"reputation_change_quarter":319,"reputation_change_month":319,"reputation_change_week":134,"reputation_change_day":28,"reputation":136341,"creation_date":1312274536,"user_type":"registered","user_id":874188,"accept_rate":62,"website_url":"http://triple.ee","link":"https://stackoverflow.com/users/874188/tripleee","profile_image":"https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZcY77.png?s=128&g=1","display_name":"tripleee"}],"has_more":false,"quota_max":300,"quota_remaining":290}
```

and https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/users/874188/posts?site=stackoverflow.com gets me the (beginning of a paginated, newest-first) list of posts by myself (including questions as well as answers, though recently I only have the latter).

I don't see an API endpoint to get the profile information (bio and avatar etc) but those should be simple to scrape as such.