# `type=jsontext` JSON results for help pages

Tags: discussion, documentation

It would greatly simplify machine reading if we could apply `type=jsontext` to API help pages, including the index.

**Update:** [Here's an unofficial JSON schema for v1.x](https://stackapps.com/questions/630/soapi-rest-complete-stackoverflow-api-specification-in-machine-readable-format).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was [deferred](https://stackapps.com/questions/112/cant-get-json-representation-for-the-help) before, but I still think it would be great feature for code generators.