# SOAPI-REST: Complete Stack Overflow API specification in machine readable format

Tags: app, api, dev-tool

### [SOAPI-REST](http://soapi.info/Services/Rest.aspx) Services

At four hour intervals, [**SOAPI-WATCH**](https://stackapps.com/questions/534/soapi-watch-a-realtime-service-that-notifies-subscribers-via-email-twitter-etc) parses the complete Stack Overflow API documentation and generates a complete object graph representing the API including all routes, parameters and return formats.

Much of the data and code generated by the various SOAPI facilities are available via a [REST](http://soapi.info/Services/Rest.aspx) endpoint.

**Status**

Parsing and code generation status history. Results are returned in descending chronological order.

- http://soapi.info/rest/status
- http://soapi.info/rest/status?limit=10

**API specifications**

The latest API specification is available in three formats. To view/download specific versions of the API see the API Status page. All results are returned as plain text.

- Text - A human friendly dump of the parsed API object graph suitable for review and differencing purposes.
  Text is the default output format.

  - http://soapi.info/rest/api
  - http://soapi.info/rest/api?format=txt
- JSON - a complete JavaScript serialization of the parsed API object graph.

  - http://soapi.info/rest/api?format=json
- JSONP - a complete JavaScript serialization of the parsed API object graph with padding.

  - http://soapi.info/rest/api?format=json&jsonp=yourJSONPCallback
- XML - a complete XML serialization of the parsed API object graph.

  - http://soapi.info/rest/api?format=xml