# Am I accessing the API correctly?

Tags: support, jsonp, json

When running the code

```
$.getJSON('http://api.stackoverflow.com/0.8/questions/4', function(data) {
    // Do some stuff here....
});
```

I get the error

> Failed to load resource

Am I accessing this wrong?

Comment: You're probably hitting some XSS blocks.

Comment: @Kevin: So what should I do differently?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I suspect your problem (as I commented) is XSS related.

Try using [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP#JSONP) instead of raw JSON; we just added support for the `jsonp` parameter.

Comment: uh, i thought it would not be supported on v1.0 API (i remember a dev.meta post about that), good!

Comment: Sweet! Just what I needed. I suggest that the `jsonp` parameter be added to the global parameters list here http://stackapps.com/questions/1/api-documentation-and-help

Comment: Nevermind... I updated it. I keep forgetting everything is a wiki :-P

Answer (score 7):

As Kevin says, XSS. Try this instead:

```
$.getJSON("http://api.stackoverflow.com/0.8/stats?jsonp=?", function(data){
alert(data.statistics[0]['total_questions']);
});
```