# jQuery Ajax calls return null

Tags: support, jquery, ajax

When I enter the API URLs into my browser they work, but when I try from jQuery they just return null. When I open the HTML below, all I get is an alert that says null, despite the fact that [Firebug](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Firebug) shows me that the correct request was made.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Test</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4/jquery.min.js"
                type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">//<![CDATA[
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $.ajax({
                    url: "http://api.stackoverflow.com/0.8/stats",
                    dataType: 'json',
                    success: function(data, text, xhr){
                        alert(data);
                        alert(text);
                        alert(xhr);
                    }
                });
            });
            //]]>
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Welcome to the wonderful world of cross domain scripting!

We do support JSONP, to alleviate this.  Just drop `jsonp=myMostFavoriteMethod` onto any request, and it'll be returned in a wrapper function invocation.

[See also.](https://stackapps.com/questions/173/am-i-accessing-the-api-correctly)