# Add 'linked' question data to the API

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, questions

SE sites show linked questions on the right column.

It would be great to add an array of ids to the question response called 'linked'.

[Example Linked Question](https://stackapps.com/questions/1/api-documentation-and-help)

Answer (score 2):

We'll consider this for a subsequent version.

---

This was added in 1.1 as [`/questions/{id}/linked`](http://api.stackoverflow.com/1.1/usage/methods/linked-questions)

Comment: That was what I thought you'd say. `:p`

Comment: @jjnguy - frozen interfaces and all.  We love throwing new features out there, but everybody would be pulling there hair out if we were changing the API interface daily.

Comment: When is 'v1.1' (or whatever it will be numbered) going to start getting tested? I'm just curious. No rush... I know you're busy. Maybe in 2 - 3 months...? A rough estimate would be great.

Comment: I figure it doesn't hurt to throw my ideas out there.  I definitely don't expect them to get implemented any time soon.