# How can I see the next page of favorites using the SO API?

Tags: discussion, support

http://api.stackoverflow.com/1.0/users/113124/favorites

only shows me 30 favourites. How can I see the rest?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First step - check the [docs](https://stackapps.com/questions/1/api-documentation-and-help)

but to answer your question, use the `page` parameter

http://api.stackoverflow.com/1.0/users/113124/favorites?page=2

---

ok, `http://api.stackoverflow.com/1.0/help/method?method=users/{id}/favorites` for the route in question `users/{id}/favorites`

each item listed under parameters can be sent as a query string parameter.

e.g.

http://api.stackoverflow.com/1.0/users/113124/favorites?page=2&pagesize=100

all of the information is there, explained in detail. The only thing missing is an example url to bridge the gap. I think that would go a long way towards making the docs more intuitive.

But in any case - there you go.. good luck.

Comment: thanks, I already checked the docs that you linked to. Where does it say that I can use the page parameter?

Answer (score 3):

Look at the documentation: http://api.stackoverflow.com/1.0/help/method?method=users/{id}/favorites

You can use the parameter pagesize to change the size of results:

eg:
http://api.stackoverflow.com/1.0/users/113124/favorites?pagesize=40

Comment: Is there some upper limit to it? `pagesize=693` doesn't work.

Comment: if you read the link I gave first you'd see it is 1 to 100 inclusive