# What is stackapps?

Tags: discussion

What exactly is stackapps?

I have search trhough the questions but did not find a straight forward answer. Why was stackapps build and why should I use it?

Comment: Look over to the right and you'll see "Get Started". That's a good place to, you know, *get started*.

Comment: @Dennis I missed this one too. It looks quite like an ad. But the *FAQ* links are quite a good place on all SX sites.

Answer (score 10):

StackApps is a member of the [StackExchange network of sites](http://stackexchange.com).

It is designed for questions about using the [Stack Exchange API](http://api.stackoverflow.com/1.1/usage) and reporting any bugs you find in it.

A good place to start is [here](https://stackapps.com/questions/1/api-documentation-and-help) which gives you an overview of what the API is all about.

If all you're looking for is *applications* that use the API, then these two pages will help you out:

- [StackList](http://stacklist.quickmediasolutions.com)
- [List of questions tagged [app]](https://stackapps.com/questions/tagged/app)

Answer (score 4):

First step: read the [FAQ](https://stackapps.com/faq)

FAQ means Frequently Asked Questions http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FAQ

Comment: Second step?