# Looking for app to support offline access to my posts?

Tags: discussion, app-request, offline

I am looking for an application to download all the questions I asked (and the answers) on Stack sites and all the questions that I labeled with the favorite label (that start what appears under the number of votes of a question) with their respective answers.

It would be interesting to have the functionality of save the questions you asked and send it in the next online moment.

Does anyone know an app like this?

Answer (score 3):

There are no app[s] like that at the moment but you could try to [make it one](https://stackapps.com/questions/1/api-documentation-and-help), it sounds an useful idea to me.

In the meanwhile, it's not 100% what you are requesting but it could work:

1. Browse
   http://www.stackprinter.com/favorites?service=stackoverflow&userid=470933&page=1
2. Print every questions in Pdf (I can do this natively on Osx, you may require some Pdf printer).

Answer (score 2):

[My app](https://stackapps.com/questions/2652/how-do-i-read-stackoverflow-questions-and-answers-in-an-offline-manner-uses-pd) converts all the questions based on a keyword into a single pdf. When little mods, you can make it behave your way.