# Does there exist an app that allows me to download all of my questions and answers on all SE sites?

Tags: support

I'm interested in downloading a backup of all my questions and answers on all Stack Exchange sites in the form of markdown files. I'm already aware of [this SE data explorer query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1529864/all-my-posts-on-the-se-network-with-markdown-and-html-content-plus-editors-and-s), but this downloads all of my questions and answers into a CSV file. I'm also aware of [this question](https://stackapps.com/q/1890/120681) that was asked over 10 years ago, but I did not see any recent answers. Does there exist an app that does this? Or would I need to make one?

Comment: Have you tried [submitting a GDPR access and/or data portability request](https://policies.stackoverflow.co/data-request/)?

Comment: @Makyen yes, but it doesn't seem to download my questions and answers in the form of Markdown files.

Comment: Are you saying it doesn't provide the Markdown? Or, are you saying that it just doesn't separate the Markdown for each question or answer into a separate file?

Comment: @Makyen the Markdown is embedded inside json files that are difficult to parse. Also, as you mentioned, the Markdown is not separated into separate question and answer files. I'm currently working on my own solution to do this using the Stack API, so we'll see how it goes...

Answer (score 1):

I created a Python script that does what I want. The announcement for it can be found [here](https://stackapps.com/questions/10503/backpack-download-all-of-your-questions-and-answers-across-all-se-sites-as-mark), and the code itself with instructions on how to use it can be found here: https://github.com/mhdadk/stack-exchange-backup