# Backpack: Download all of your questions and answers across all SE sites as Markdown files

Tags: app

#### Screenshot / Code Snippet

[image]
[image]
[image]

#### About

This app is used to download a user's questions and answers across all Stack Exchange (SE) sites that they are registered for. The questions and answers are downloaded in the form of Markdown files, as shown in the screenshots above. The purpose of this app is to obtain a backup of all questions and answers for a user.

This app consists of a Python script that makes use of the [SE API](https://api.stackexchange.com/). To start using this app, follow the instructions [here](https://github.com/mhdadk/stack-exchange-backup/blob/main/README.md).

#### License

MIT License

#### Download

Follow the instructions at the GitHub repository [here](https://github.com/mhdadk/stack-exchange-backup).

#### Platform

PC, Mac, and Linux

#### Contact

[Mahmoud Abdelkhalek](https://github.com/mhdadk)

#### Code

Code can be found [here](https://github.com/mhdadk/stack-exchange-backup)