# Non-verbatim search strings in py-stackexchange

Tags: support, api, questions, python, search

I am writing a python program with py-stackexchange that takes a query and returns a list of urls to questions with that query in the title.

Here's the code:

```
#!c:/Python27/python.exe -u
import sys
sys.path.append('.')

import stackexchange
so = stackexchange.Site(stackexchange.StackOverflow)

def getLinkList(qry):
    qs = so.search(intitle=qry)
    retList = []

    for q in qs:
         retList.append(q.url)

    return retList
```

The problem is, the qry string must appear verbatim in the title of the question, and I want it to return questions that are the closest to the qry string as possible (highest number of similar words), sort of like a search engine for questions.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: You might find, now that version 1.1 of the API has been released, that the `/similar` method might suit your needs (http://api.stackoverflow.com/1.1/usage/methods/similar). You can access this in Py-StackExchange with the `site.similar()` method; just remember to update the library to a recent version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you can't do it because py-stackexchange is a library based on [SE API](https://stackapps.com/questions/1/api-documentation-and-help) that does not provide that kind of search.
You should use [Google API search](http://code.google.com/intl/it-IT/apis/customsearch/v1/using_rest.html#query-params) instead.