# Can we have the usage pages linked to the side bar?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, stackapps, api-v1.1, getting-started

The usage page for the API used in [the blog](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/02/stack-exchange-api-1-1-and-improved-app-gallery/) is a very good reference of the current API methods, and slightly better then the current documentation link in [the FAQ](https://stackapps.com/questions/1/api-documentation-and-help).

Would it at all be possible to have the new links for the [1.0](http://api.stackoverflow.com/1.0/usage) and [1.1](http://api.stackoverflow.com/1.1/usage) API added to the Getting Started section on the left hand side.

I currently use these documents a lot, and have to admit quickly forget the URL and find myself going back to the blog to get it. I have looked through Stack Apps and can't seem to find these links easily.

Comment: This is [status-completed]. The API usage demo and docs have long been listed in the "Get Started" section, of the right-hand column, of [the home page](http://stackapps.com/). See the API 2.2 -> [Documentation link](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs).